# Finding a vector satisfying certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

$a$ and $b$ are [column vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors) and $c$ is a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)). You can view x as a column vector.

1. $x ∈ R^n$
2. $∀x_i ∈ x, x_i \ge 0$
3. $c.x \leq b$
4. $a^T.x$ is minimized for all possible values of $x$ which satisfies the first three conditions.

If $a ∈ R^n$ for some positive integer $n$, and $b  ∈ R^m$ for some [positive integer](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveInteger.html) $m$, than $c  ∈ R^{nxm}$. You can further assume that there is at least one possible value of $x$ that satisfies the first three conditions. Find x.

I am having difficulty about understanding the problem above and finding x. I have understood the first two conditions but can't understand the third and fourth conditions. Would someone help me please? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: if $c \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}$, then the product $cx$ is not defined. So, it's not clear what you're trying to say for condition 3.

Comment: Should the last condition instead be "$a^Tx$ is minimized..."?

Comment: Yes. It should be $a^Tx$. Sorry for my mistake. What should I understand for last condition?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that we should instead have $a \in \Bbb R^n$, $b \in \Bbb R^m$, $c \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$, and that condition 4 is supposed to be that $a^Tx$ is minimized.

In other words, you are considering the minimization problem
$$
\min a^Tx \quad \text{s.t.} \quad cx \leq b,\ x \geq 0.
$$
if we replace $\min a^Tx$ with the equivalent $\max (-a)^Tx$, then this is the canonical form for a [linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). There is no closed form for the answer, which means that there is no general answer the question of "find $x$" as a function of $a,b,c$.  However, there are algorithms by which instances of this problem may be solved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know anything about the algorithms you have mentioned?

Comment: Yes, but if you're interested then the best course of action for you is to find a textbook or online notes that describe these algorithms

Comment: I have made some research about linear programming but I still don't understand how to solve a canonical form of a linear program. Would you share me some useful sources to solve these kind of problem?

Comment: @OğuzhanKarahan See [this explanation](https://people.richland.edu/james/ictcm/2006/simplex.html) of the simplex method, for instance

Comment: @OğuzhanKarahan If you want a textbook, I would recommend Vanderbei's, which seems to be available online